# Altium IPC Footprint wizard Generating Dodgy Components

Tags: altium, footprint, ipc

I've started using Altium Designer 14 after a break and needed to build some components I started with a EP4CE10 FPGA, but I noticed that despite following the component guidelines as close as possible, I was generating rubbish.

Is it possible some setting somewhere has been changed to cause these errors?

I cannot see any errors between the manufacturers numbers and my own (attached). I also tried generating a soic 8, but again it produces rubbish.

The datasheet: [datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/packaging/04r00402-01.pdf)

The output:

[image: Wizard Output]

My input:

[image: input1]
[image: input2]

Comment: Why don't you ask Altium support?

Comment: I have been using Altium for like 10 years and have never used the Wizard; actually I used it once and did not like the results.  I create/build most of my PCB footprints (in the Library Editor) using datasheet parameters and sometimes importing .dxf shapes from the manufacture websites.

Comment: If you measure the generated footprint in the footprint editor, can you find which dimension doesn't match the inputs you gave? For example, is the distance between the ends of the pads on opposite sides slightly larger than the value you gave for dimension E? (etc)

Comment: I've seen no such problems with the IPC wizard from 9 to 18. It looks like the pitch is set way off (like 0.8mm rather than 0.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they screwed up on D vs D1 and E vs E1, after changing to 20mm it worked.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Altium will generate footprints like that if the number of pins and/or the pitch are set too high compared to the chip's physical dimensions. That results in rows of pins that don't fit in the chip's shape.

So double check your values... and your units!